# CSS aspect-ratio not working properly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, aspect-ratio

I created a simple div with aspect-ratio property set as a child of another div. The inner div have to fill whole possible space (but still respect passed aspect ratio).

It works as expected on chromium based browsers, but on firefox it seems like its ignoring the aspect-ratio when width: 100% is set and inner div end up stretched.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Sample content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the width to 100% if you don't want it to be 100% wide?

Comment: @xdumaine I want it to be 100% wide as long as max height not being achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `aspect-ratio` is a [weak declaration](https://css-tricks.com/weak-declaration/) so what you get in Firefox can be considered as correct because the element is respecting `width` and `max-height` prior to `aspect-ratio`. I would even say that the behavior of Chrome is the wrong one.

Worth to note that `aspect-ratio` only set a **preferred aspect ratio** <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#aspect-ratio)</sup> to give a similar behavior to image element that have intrinsic aspect ratio. It was never meant to *force* the ratio of the element.

Use image in your example and you will get the same result as in Firefox

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;*/
}

.container {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/300" class="box">
</div>
```

The above will give you a stretched image which confirm the correct behavior of Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Using max-width: 100% instead, works fine for me in chrome and firefox:

```css
.box {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Sample content
  </div>
</div>
```